# FTP view doesn't show files deployed through Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying Asp.Net 6.0 WebApi application through Azure DevOps/Releases.
It runs "Deploy Azure App Service" to deploy the application. Deployment goes through successfully. Application works.

But when I connect to same App Service through FTP, files don't show.
Inside /site/wwwroot/ there is only hostingstart.html.

What am I doing wrong? Where are the files actually stored? Why is FTP not showing the files?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the folder structure of your WebApp?

Comment: Does your issue got resolved ?

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue and it's absolutely baffling, where is the documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same behaviour and was able to resolve by changing deployment method to Web Deploy. I belive new default setup is running the site from zip package. So changing to web deploy will re-enable ftp access [image]